# Geolocation with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation

Is there a way to get `lat/long` into `PHP` in a single file solution? Normally using `JS` I would use this in a pure `JS` sulution, but now I need the values in `PHP` variables:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation);
    } else {
        $('#location').html('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
    }
});
function showLocation(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    return latitude;
}
</script>
```

I need to get the `lat/lon`g vars into `PHP` without using an `AJAX` post into a url: xxx.php type of sulution. Single file only. Any ideas on a clean way to execute this anyone?

BTW- If I write them into cookies this only works if I reload the doc. :-(

Thanks!

Comment: PHP runs on the server so asking fo the location in PHP will return the servers location. Is that what you are looking for? If not then some kind of clientside code is needed.

Comment: Since the script correctly returns the latitude, longitude of the browser, I need to get them to php vars (possibly) without using AJAX. If possible.

Comment: The page needs to load for the JS to run. The PHP isn't not present once the page has loaded. You could send an ajax request to the PHP with the address which wouldn't require a reload. Why can't ajax be used, JS is already required for this solution.

Comment: The AJAX examples that I have seen only pass the data into forms. Is there a way to pass the data into a PHP var using a single page solution, or am I heading down there wrong path?

Comment: You can assign PHP var to js variable but you can't assign js va to PHP variable. IMO put your js variable to hidden field of the form and submit that form using PHP. You'll get it in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use geoplugin api  [Link](https://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php)

```
<?php
  echo var_export(unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp? 
  ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])));
?>
```

Comment: But this only uses the IP. That is nowhere near accurate.

Comment: I have something similar in place now. The reason I want o use browser based geolocation is to cure some inaccuracy issues that came up.

Comment: this is the location of the server, based upon an IP - nothing to do with geolocation. not good answer to have accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I did this
In the JS (g1.php):

> function showPosition(position) {
>      var latlon =  position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
>      var prog = "g2.php?latlon=" + latlon;
>      location.href = prog;}

and then did this in g2.php

> $field = explode(',', $_GET['latlon']);

I don't know if it is good programming but it works