# How can I changing PHP code using country code

Tags: php

I would like to change  PaymentMethodStatus::ACTIVE to PaymentMethodStatus::INACTIVE when country code is not IN. what code should i use?

```
public function isEnable()
{
    if (!$this->isActive()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->paymentMethod->status==PaymentMethodStatus::ACTIVE) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
```

Comment: Can you get the country code? Where should it come from? The domain? The IP address? What the user reports to you?

Comment: One of the ways: Geolocation . See this [SO_link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53474812/geolocation-with-php) (then check the geoplugin_countryCode )